# mvc dropdownlist selected items can't reselect

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

In a view (UserPicture.aspx), I have a dropdownlist of users, an image, a file upload and a submit button. When I change the selected user, I want to change the displayed image to the corresponding profile picture. Every thing works fine until I modify the image for a user, using fileupload and submit button. After that, if I try to reselect the changed user, **the javascript function doesn't fire the $.get(...) to the controller anymore**. All unchanged users still fire the $get()...

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

---

My view items:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("cbUsers", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.cbUsers, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "onChange", "swapImage()" } })%>

<input type="file" name="myImage" id="myImage"/>

<div id="ProfilePicture">
    <img alt="Profile picture" src="../../images/img_profile.png" />
</div>

<button type="submit"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Update" /></button>
```

How I get the image path:

```
function swapImage() {
    var e = document.getElementById("cbUsers");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    $.get("/Admin/GetUserProfilePath",
    { val1: strUser },
    function (data) {
        document.getElementById("ProfilePicture").innerHTML = "<img src='" + data + "' alt='Profile picture' class='searchPicture'/>";
    });
};
```

With this finction in the controller returning the image path:

```
 public ActionResult GetUserProfilePath(string val1)
```

The submit button triggers this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UserPicture(object cbUsers, HttpPostedFileBase myImage)
{
    HandleUploadedFile(cbUsers, myImage);
    ViewBag.cbUsers = new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>();//Get the users list
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a caching issue. Try adding this attribute to your GetUserProfilePath() action:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Or change `.get()` to `.ajax({ type: 'get' })` with `cache:false`

Comment: An other solution that worked, was to use POST instead of GET, in the original code.